# BigQuery PHP API - large query result memory bloat - even with paging

Tags: php, google-bigquery

I am running a range of queries in BigQuery and exporting them to CSV via PHP. There are reasons why this is the easiest method for me to do this (multiple queries dependent on variables within an app).

I am struggling with memory issues when the result set is larger than 100mb. It appears that the memory usage of my code seems to grow in line with the result set, which I thought would be avoided by paging. Here is my code:

```
$query = $bq->query($myQuery);
$queryResults = $bq->runQuery($query,['maxResults'=>5000]);

$FH = fopen($storagepath, 'w');

$rows = $queryResults->rows();

foreach ($rows as $row) {
    fputcsv($FH, $row);
}

fclose($FH);
```

The `$queryResults->rows()` function returns a Google Iterator which uses paging to scroll through the results, so I do not understand why memory usage grows as the script runs.

Am I missing a way to discard previous pages from memory as I page through the results?

**UPDATE**

I have noticed that actually since upgrading to the v1.4.3 BigQuery PHP API, the memory usage does cap out at 120mb for this process, even when the result set reaches far beyond this (currently processing a 1gb result set). But still, 120mb seems too much. How can I identify and fix where this memory is being used?

**UPDATE 2**
This 120mb seems to be tied at 24kb per `maxResult` in the page. E.g. adding 1000 rows to `maxResults` adds 24mb of memory. So my question is now **why is 1 row of data using 24kb in the Google Iterator? Is there a way to reduce this? The data itself is < 1kb per row.**

Comment: Why not export the results to Cloud Storage in CSV format and then copy the file?

Comment: I couldn't see a way to export a query directly to CSV. I can save the results to a table and then export the table, but this requires me to create a load of temporary tables as I run queries, plus cleanup etc. Is there a way to export query results directly to CSV?

Comment: Running a query always creates a temporary table, which you can export.

Comment: Please can you point me in the direction of how to do this? I can't find it in the docs.

Comment: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/exporting-data, and see also the `configuration.query.destinationTable` property in https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/jobs. It's populated after running a query.

Comment: Thanks, this works when the result is under 1gb but my issue is really on results over 1gb. I cannot shard as the CSV file is an input to another system. Any more thoughts? Thank you v much for help so far.

Comment: See here --> https://twitter.com/polleyg/status/982046789460099072

Comment: Thank you again. The compose command has a limit of 32 files. My 1gb file is sharding into over 100 7mb shards. This is supposed to be a big data solution!! Is there a way to increase shard size? Otherwise I guess I need to write a recursive script to compose the composed parts...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Answering my own question**

The extra memory is used by a load of PHP type mapping and other data structure info that comes alongside the data from BigQuery. Unfortunately I couldn't find a way to reduce the memory usage below around 24kb per row multiplied by the page size. *If someone finds a way to reduce the bloat that comes along with the data please post below*.

However thanks to one of the comments I realized you can extract a query directly to CSV in a Google Cloud Storage Bucket. This is really easy:

```
query = $bq->query($myQuery);

$queryResults = $bq->runQuery($query);

$qJobInfo = $queryResults->job()->info();

$dataset = $bq->dataset($qJobInfo['configuration']['query']['destinationTable']['datasetId']);

$table = $dataset->table($qJobInfo['configuration']['query']['destinationTable']['tableId']);

$extractJob = $table->extract('gs://mybucket/'.$filename.'.csv');

$table->runJob($extractJob);
```

However this still didn't solve my issue as my result set was over 1gb, so I had to make use of the data sharding function by adding a wildcard.

```
$extractJob = $table->extract('gs://mybucket/'.$filename.'*.csv');
```

This created ~100 shards in the bucket. These need to be recomposed using `gsutil compose <shard filenames> <final filename>`. However, `gsutil` only lets you compose 32 files at a time. Given I will have variable numbers of shards, opten above 32, I had to write some code to clean them up.

```
//Save above job as variable
$eJob = $table->runJob($extractJob);

$eJobInfo = $eJob->info();

//This bit of info from the job tells you how many shards were created
$eJobFiles = $eJobInfo['statistics']['extract']['destinationUriFileCounts'][0];

$composedFiles = 0; $composeLength = 0; $subfile = 0; $fileString = "";

while (($composedFiles < $eJobFiles) && ($eJobFiles>1)) {

    while (($composeLength < 32) && ($composedFiles < $eJobFiles)) {
        // gsutil creates shards with a 12 digit number after the filename, so build a string of 32 such filenames at a time                            
        $fileString .= "gs://bucket/$filename" . str_pad($composedFiles,12,"0",STR_PAD_LEFT) . ".csv ";

        $composedFiles++;

        $composeLength++;

    }

    $composeLength = 0;

    // Compose a batch of 32 into a subfile
    system("gsutil compose $fileString gs://bucket/".$filename."-".$subfile.".csv");

    $subfile++;

    $fileString="";
}

if ($eJobFiles > 1) {
    //Compose all the subfiles                        
    system('gsutil compose gs://bucket/'.$filename.'-* gs://fm-sparkbeyond/YouTube_1_0/' . $filepath . '.gz') ==$
}
```

Note in order to give my Apache user access to `gsutil` I had to allow the user to create a `.config` directory in the web root. Ideally you would use the gsutil PHP library, but I didn't want the code bloat.

**If anyone has a better answer please post it**

1. Is there a way to get smaller output from the BigQuery library than 24kb per row?
2. Is there a more efficient way to clean up variable numbers of shards?